# react-router-dom5 active class

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating basic routing in react-router-5

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

And in navbar.js like this

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="/home">
        Good Site
      </a>
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              className="nav-link"
              to="/"
              activeClassName="active-link"
            >
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              className="nav-link"
              to="/about"
              activeClassName="active-link"
            >
              About
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              className="nav-link"
              to="/contact"
              activeClassName="active-link"
            >
              Contact
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

the problem i am facing is that the home route always have `active-link` class. What i am doing wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is occuring becuse of all other routes have the "/" as part of them - so it is being selected as a part of any other selected NavLink.

If you put `exact` in your NavLink as well as in the Route - it should resolve the problem since the route now will only match the selected route link and if the user is not selecting a route then the home page will be selected via the "/" route link.

```
 ...
 <li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink
      className="nav-link"
      exact to="/"
      activeClassName="active-link"
    >
      Home
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink
      className="nav-link"
      exact to="/about"
      activeClassName="active-link"
    >
      About
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  ...
```

Comment: so for every route i have to add,  exact.

Comment: Yes - thats what I am suggesting.